# Adding content to Bootstrap modal using AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal, bootstrap-carousel

I am trying to make a slideshow (Bootstrap Carousel) inside a Bootstrap modal. For that matter, I want to dynamically add new slide containers giving data using AngularJS. So far, I am able to make slide 1 and have done that using objects and then passing values to them through functions.

I want to pass 3 or four functions with content like, images, description and heading and the code should add new items in the carousel.

here is the index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="modalApp">
  <head>
    <title>This is a custom modal</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.6.5/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div ng-controller="modalAppController">

      <button class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#whatsNewModal">Open Modal</button>
      <!-- Whats New feature modal -->
<div id="whatsNewModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
      <div class="modal-content">

        <!-- Modal Header -->

        <div class="modal-header">
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">x</button>
          <h3 class="modal-title" style="color: #000"><strong><i class="fa fa-bullhorn" style="margin-right: 10px"></i><span>What's New</span></strong></h3>
        </div>

        <!-- Modal Body/Modal Content -->

        <div class="modal-body">
          <div id="whatsNewCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel" data-interval="3000">

            <!-- Carousel Images -->

            <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
              <div class="item">
                  <img ng-src="{{modalContent.Src}}" alt="New Features Screenshots" class="img-fluid d-block">
                  <hr>

                  <div class="content">
                    <center>
                      <h3>{{modalContent.Head}}</h3>
                      <h4>{{modalContent.Desc}}</h4>
                    </center>
                  </div>
                </div>

            <!-- Carousel Controls -->

            <a class="left carousel-control" href="#whatsNewCarousel" role="button" data-slide="prev" style="background: transparent">
              <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true" style="color: #dcdde1; top: 40%; left: 10px; font-size: 40px"></span>
              <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
            </a>
            <a class="right carousel-control" href="#whatsNewCarousel" role="button" data-slide="next" style="background: transparent">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true" style="color: #dcdde1; top: 40%; right: 22px; font-size: 40px"></span>
                <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
            </a>
          </div>
        </div>

      </div>
    </div>
</div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

app.js

```
(function(){
  'use strict';

  angular.module('modalApp', [])
  .controller('modalAppController', modalAppController)
  modalAppController.$inject = ['$scope'];
  function modalAppController($scope){
    $scope.carouselData = function(src, head, desc){
      $scope.modalContent = {
        Src : src,
        Head: head,
        Desc: desc
      };
    };

    $scope.carouselData("Screen.png", "Feature 1", "Here goes the description");
    $scope.carouselData("Screen2.png", "Feature 2", "Here goes the description"); // I want to pass more functions like this.
  }
})();
```

Comment: You should use https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/ to achieve this. And kick jQuery please =)

Comment: Yeah, I should consider that, but is there any way, I can achieve the same with this.

Comment: Where is your `carouselData` function called?

Comment: the carouselData function is called in app.js

Comment: Please create a working fiddle and explain your problem.

Comment: Fiddle is not working for me, so here is the codepen.io link: https://codepen.io/s4tr2/pen/RQQLRR